# Unexpected T_String PHP Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I seem to be getting an unexpected T_STRING when I run this php code on my wordpress website. The goal is to have customised banners along the top of each post and the problem area appears to be the third line of the attached code...

```
   <div id="header-middle">
<?php bannerAd('template-header'); ?>
<?php if ((get_post_meta("$post->ID", '_as_roomname', true)=='Party Casino') bannerad('party-casino'); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: You need 1 more bracket at the end, thats why it's 'unexpected'.

Comment: @Monkeyzeus The OP has identified the offending line as the third line in the code snippet. Your edits make it more difficult to find the error without adding much to the clarity of the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)` in the if statement

Comment: `<?php if ((get_post_meta("$post->ID", '_as_roomname', true)=='Party Casino') ***HERE*** ) ***HERE*** bannerad('party-casino'); ?>`

Comment: @SetSailMedia correct, the end of the if statement